# Python - creating XML by reading XML resulting "number:" word in file.write

Tags: python, xml, xlrd

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to generate xml file with the code below:

```
file = open("filename.xml","w")
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')
value = worksheet.cell(1, 2)
file.write("<raml xmlns="'"raml21.xsd"'" version="'"2.1"'">")
file.write("    <cmData scope="'"all"'" type="'"plan"'">")
file.write("        <managedObject class="'"BTS"'" distName="'"ID-%s"'" operation="'"create"'" version="'"1891"'">" % str(value))
```

But then the output is like this:

```
<managedObject version="1891" operation="create" distName="ID-number:1900.0" class="BTS">
```

The value of `cell(1,2)` should be 1900.
Why is the output in the file *"number:1900.0"*? I was expecting it 1900 only. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the value of `str(value)` by printing it out. It is likely that it is "number:1900.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the method [`cell(rowx, colx)`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=cell#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.cell), which returns a `Cell` object.
That's why `str(value)` in your code returns `number:1900.0`.

You want to use the method [`cell_value(rowx, colx)`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=cell#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.cell_value), which returns value of the cell. But you still will get a float number. So if you expect value to be integer, you can cast it like this:

```
value = worksheet.cell_value(1, 2)
id = int(value)
```

Alternatively, you can use the attribute [`value`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=cell#xlrd.sheet.Cell) of the `Cell` object.
For example:

```
value = worksheet.cell(1, 2).value
id = int(value)
```